# Can I use openpyxl python3 package on Pyinstaller?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, automation, package

I want to create an excel automation application using python3. Can I use openpyxl python3 package on Pyinstaller so that my program executable to other users? If not, what kind of package you suggest?

Comment: Yes you can....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First, install PyInstaller with pip:

`pip install pyinstaller`

Windows: Open a command prompt or PowerShell and cd to your folder containing your script. Write the following and press Enter:

`pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py`

You can find the frozen exe from the dist folder.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer.
But, what do you mean frozen exe and dist folder? Bcs im totally beginner

Comment: It is called freezing because all modules and scripts are packed into one executable. Pyinstaller puts the main executable into the dist folder created during freezing. Read more here: https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/